# Best practice for Service Account accessing Cloud Services from iOS app without user login?

Tags: ios, azure, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, ssl-certificate

Hi my company needs to create an iOS app that sends secure data to our own cloud services, such as our Google Drive or some REST web services. What is the best practice that does not require user login?

I came upon some technical articles mentioning about client certificate for authentication of the service account. Or using 2 legged OAuth 2.0 with a service account. Although I am not exactly sure how to implement them.

So just wondering perhaps there are some best practices that I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the service accounts, this way your users don't need to login to check out files. The service account will act on the user's behalf depending on the API called. Do note that files accessed will be from the service account's set email.

More information about Service Accounts can be found on the Drive's [Domain-wide delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation) (though its Drive v2), or the Google Identity's [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) page.

Comment: Thank you. What about web services? How can the app access a secured/authenticated RESTful web service without user login?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the notes on this page about the limitations with service accounts and google Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation